# Nested SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Today at work I used a query that ressembled that one:

```
Update myTable mt_1 Set (VALUE_1, VALUE_2) = 
(
   Select val_1 as VALUE_1, val_2 as VALUE_2 
  From myTable mt_2
  Where mt_2.ID = mt_1.ID
  )
```

It worked perfectly but then, I needed to nest my query this way:

```
Update myTable mt_1 Set (VALUE_1, VALUE_2) = 
(
    Select * From (
       Select val_1 as VALUE_1, val_2 as VALUE_2 
       From myTable mt_2
       Where mt_2.ID = mt_1.ID
     )
  )
```

And there, Oracle yelled at me saying that the field "mt_1"."ID" was unknown somehow.

Is that normal behaviour that by nesting a query, tables defined outside but not overriden anywhere else lose their scope (mt_1 here)? How do I bypass this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `mt_1` alias as opposed to the first query. See 1st line below.

```
Update myTable mt_1 Set (VALUE_1, VALUE_2) = 
(
    Select * From (
       Select val_1 as VALUE_1, val_2 as VALUE_2 
       From myTable mt_2
       Where mt_2.ID = mt_1.ID
     )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that was a typo here :P I did not miss it with the original query sorry